# How to show hide buttons in angular4

Tags: angular, uibutton, angular4-forms, angular-forms

I am new to angular, so I have an edit button on clicking which I need to show two buttons i.e save and cancel buttons and hide the edit button. And on clicking cancel, I need to show only edit button. I am stuck in toggling this through angular and ngIF.

Here is my buttons code in form:

```
<button id="editBtn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="isValid=!isValid" class="btn modal-btn btn-default" [disabled]="isValid">Edit</button>
                                <button id="submitBtn" [disabled]="!isValid" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn modal-btn btn-default"[disabled]="!isValid" >Submit</button>
                                <button id="Cancel"  type="button" (click)="isValid=!isValid" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn modal-btn btn-default" [disabled]="!isValid">Cancel</button>
```

Earlier I was using [disabled] but now I need to show /hide.

Comment: You can use 'hidden' instead of 'disabled'. If you don't want the button as all in the dom, you can use *ngIf, as suggested in trichetriche's answer

Answer (score 6):

Simply replace

```
[disabled]="condition"
```

By

```
*ngIf="condition"
```

Answer (score 3):

In template

```
<button (click)="enableEdit = true">Edit</button>  
<button *ngIf="enableEdit">Save</button>  
<button *ngIf="enableEdit" (click)="enableEdit=false">Cancel</button>
```

In .ts file

```
enableEdit: boolean = false;
```